# c pthread passing array of type int

Tags: c, arrays, pthreads

I am passing an array of type int pthread_create and getting error:

```
  histogram.c:138:3: warning: passing argument 3 of
 ‘pthread_create’ from incompatible   pointer type [enabled by default]
  expected ‘void * (*)(void *)’ but argument is of type ‘void * (*)(int *)’

  void *output_results();
  pthread_create(&t2, NULL, output_results, (void *)bins);

  void *output_results(int *bins) {
      some code
  }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Should be

```
void *output_results(void*);
pthread_create(&t2, NULL, output_results, (void *)bins);

void *output_results(void *data) {
    int *bins = (int*)data;
    // some code
}
```

The error message is pretty clear: the function should be of type `void * (*)(void *)` and not `void * (*)(int *)` (plus your prototype for `output_results` was not matching its definition).

Comment: didnt think of that, why didn't the cast work in the pthread_create ?

Comment: You were casting the fourth argument of `pthread_create` whereas the problem is about the third one: the function pointer. The prototype of `pthread_create` requires the third argument to be of type `void * (*)(void *)`.

Answer (score 0):

The compilation error is because `pthread_create` expects `void *output_results(void *bins)`, but you have `int *bins`.

Also, the declaration of `output_results` you're using does not match its definition.